# Will older (pre-2008) MAPP torches work with new (MAP/Pro) cylinders?

Tags: plumbing, gas, soldering

I recently inherited a pair of 70s/80s-era MAPP torches in good condition (both work with their current cylinders).

I know that the formulation of what's sold in the USA as MAPP changed around 2008, so I'm wondering: can I use these torch heads with the "MAPP" (aka "MAP/Pro") cylinders being sold today?

(expected use is plumbing, soldering/de-soldering copper)

EDITED TO ADD: Torches are the simple screw-on-cylinder type.  I think one might be Bernz-O-Matic & the other one is Craftsman (I'm at work & don't have them in front of me right now)

Comment: Pics might help. You can [edit] your question to include one.

Comment: If they are the small torches that fit on top of the small cylinders, I think they are mainly general propose, used on propane/mapp/mapp pro.

Comment: @crip659 - yes, the torches in question are the screw-on-cylinder type.  I always assumed that there was some difference in the way the different gases burn that meant that the torches (e.g. for propane & MAPP) were not interchangeable, even if they would physically screw onto either type of cylinder.  Was I wrong about that?

Comment: MAPP usually burns hotter than propane, but not enough to require different head.  Usually fittings/accessories are made differently if they are not supposed to be used together.